# What's the name for this sports machine?

Tags: image-identification

What's the name for this sport machine?

I've tried to translate it from my native language but I couldn't find its translation.

[image]

Comment: A fitness frame?

Comment: Reverse GIS says "power tower".

Comment: A side note: in colloquial English, we would generally not call this a **machine** because it has no moving parts. I would call it a piece of **exercise equipment**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be known by a number of different names, but predominantly appears to be called a *power tower* - see [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_tower_(exercise)).

This [website](https://www.ukgymequipment.com/strength-training-c8/strength-equipment-c25/leg-raise-chin-dip-frame-p1384) calls a similar-looking frame a "Leg Raise / Chin / Dip Frame".

Comment: It seems to be called very commonly: *Power tower*. See here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267201/whats-the-name-for-this-sports-machine?noredirect=1#comment499235_267201 and on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_tower_(exercise)

Comment: @JudiciousAllure thanks i've updated my answer to include that,